# Using GPUImageFilter change values dynamically

Tags: ios, image-processing, video-processing, gpuimage

I was using `GPUImage library` [here](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) , and has lots of samples available to help, but I have found one thing while using filters its works fine with `GPUImageVideoCamera`. I was trying to apply filters on already recorded video, filter are working properly but when I try to change the value of the filter it doesn't reflect with it, since I am not using `GPUImageVideoCamera`, because I don't have to record video, but I have to implement filter preview and then apply the selected filter and create a new movie.

Below I am putting in some of my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Creating Filter
    filter=[[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];

    //Playing Video
    [self playVideo];
}

-(void)playVideo{

    if(!movieFile){
        movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:self.videoURL];
        movieFile.playAtActualSpeed=YES;
        movieFile.playSound=YES;
        movieFile.delegate=self;
    }



    [movieFile addTarget:filter];

    CGRect rect=self.viewMovie.frame;
    rect.origin=CGPointZero;


    self.filterView=[[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [self.viewMovie addSubview:self.filterView];

    //Rotate the preview to fix portrait recored video to show properly
    if([self.transformation isEqualToString:@"portrait"]){
        self.filterView.rotation=kGPUImageRotateRight;
    }

    [self.filterView initMovie];
    [filter addTarget:self.filterView];


    double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [movieFile startProcessing];
    });

}

- (IBAction)sliderAction:(id)sender {
    [self applySliderValue:self.slider.value];
}

//Doesn't work
-(void)applySliderValue:(float)sliderValue{
    [((GPUImageSepiaFilter *)filter) setIntensity:sliderValue];
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see that same behavior with the SimpleVideoFileFilter sample application, which does just this. If you move the slider there, the filter updates dynamically with the playing video being passed through it. Make sure your slider is indeed sending proper update events with correct values (0.0-1.0) to your callback method.

Comment: @BradLarson Yes the sample works fine because it use 'GPUImageVideoCamera', but I am not using the camera here, I am trying to play the video with filters applied on it, that works fine, but when I change the values of the filter that doesn't work. Yes the values I am getting are correct as you mentioned..

Comment: No, the SimpleVideoFileFilter uses a GPUImageMovie. Look at that one specifically. Like I said, it works as intended there.

Comment: @BradLarson so my code should work anyway, right? I will check the slider values again.. Thanks for insights though..

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest debugging the nib connection of your slider first:

```
-(void)applySliderValue:(float)sliderValue{
    NSLog(@"sliderValue: %f",sliderValue);
    [((GPUImageSepiaFilter *)filter) setIntensity:sliderValue];
}
```

If all is wired up correctly, you should see your debugger pop a rapid sequence of values between 0.0 and 1.0 as you move the slider around.

If nothing happens, you have nib configuration issues. If the values range outside of 0.0-1.0, you have UISlider configuration issues.

If that's working fine and the filter is still not responding dig a bit deeper by overriding this method within a custom subclass of GPUImageSepiaFilter:

```
- (void)setIntensity:(CGFloat)newIntensity;
{
    _intensity = newIntensity;

    NSLog(@"intensity: %f",_intensity);

    [self setFloat:_intensity forUniform:intensityUniform program:filterProgram];
}
```